# How to create sqlite database from Java library and use it in android application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing an android application.

I want to create different modules for UI, Business logic, and Tests.
I have created Java library for the business logic module and have added it's dependency in UI module.

Now I want to handle SQLite DB operations from this java library.
But It is not possible to handle those without android context.

Can we create SQLite database without android context in Java library? OR  can we inject the android context as a dependency in java library? How?

Comment: `But It is not possible to handle those without android context.` then just pass it to the library.